# Почему аргументы передаются в виде массива

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, в нее передаются аргументы, по какой причине мы можем получить массив этих аргументов? Как это работает?

```js
const someFunc = (...a) => a.map(el => el * 2)

console.log(someFunc(4, 6, 19));
```

Comment: rest параметры, при такой записи все параметры будут собраны в массив `a` автоматически, https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Rest_parameters

Comment: Не совсем понятно, в чем именно вопрос. ``map`` возвращает массив.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы. Просто было не очень понятно почему rest собирает в массив все аргументы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

оператор ...rest (в вашем случае ...a) собирает все переданные аргументы в масив, который вы и обрабатываете при помощи .map

```
    const someFunc = (...a) => a.map(el => el * 2)

    console.log(Array.isArray(someFunc(4, 6, 19)));
    //вернет true - возвращен массив
```

или надо вернуть масив параметров?